# React MDBTable render each item in table

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and using the MDBDataTable from

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/#a-api-references-table

```
<MDBDataTable
    striped
    bordered
    hover
    paging={false}
    data={data}
/>
```

I am trying to add a href to each element in the table, based on the pk of each row.

Something like this:

```
<MDBDataTable
    striped
    bordered
    hover
    paging={false}
    data={data}

    renderItem={item => (
      <MDBDataTable.Item
        key={item.pk}

      >

        <MDBDataTable.Item.Meta

          title={
            <a href={`/item/${item.pk}`}>
              {item.word}
            </a>}

          description={item.explanation}
        />


        {item.description}

      </MDBDataTable.Item>

    )}
    />
```

which gives me the following error:

*Warning: Invalid value for prop `renderitem` on table tag. Either  remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.*

I have seen the renderItem work on List from antd, but have no idea how to get similar behavior with the MDBDataTable.
Any idea how to accomplish the href thing?

Answer (score 1):

there is no `renderItem` prop for MDBDataTable component. it can be done via basic usage of the table:

```
<MDBTable>
  <MDBTableHead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
    </tr>
  </MDBTableHead>
  <MDBTableBody>
    {
       data.map((item,key) => <tr> <td> <a href={`/item/${item.pk}`}> {item.word} </a> </td> <td> {item.desc} </td> </tr>)
    }
  </MDBTableBody>
</MDBTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add an href when creating the rows data.

```
let rowsData = []
for (var index = 0; index < myDataSet.length; index++) {
    let rowItem = {}
    rowItem["word"] = myDataSet[index].word

    rowItem["word"] =  <a href={`/item/${myDataSet[index].pk}`}>
                          {rowItem["word"]}
                        </a>
    rowsData.push(rowItem)
}
this.setState({
    tableRows: rowsData,
});

let data = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: 'Word',
      field: 'word',
      sort: 'asc',
      width: 150
    },
    ...
  ],
  rows: this.state.tableRows

}

<MDBDataTable
    striped
    bordered
    hover
    paging={false}
    data={data}
/>
```